# How to setup RabbitMq to listen localhost address only?

Tags: binding, rabbitmq, ubuntu-20.04

I want to secure my rabbitmq installation and use 127.0.0.1 as binding interface. I'm working with an Ubuntu 20.04 machine. I have 2 plugins: stomp and management.

I found this solution:
create this file `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf`  (NB: .conf! not .config!)
and store:

```
listeners.tcp.1    = 127.0.0.1:5672
stomp.listeners.tcp.1 = 127.0.0.1:61613
management.tcp.port = 15672
management.tcp.ip   = 127.0.0.1
```

The plugins and main listener are now working on 127.0.0.1 address, but calling this command:

```
netstat -ltnp
```

I still se these two records coming from RabbitMq:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25672           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      66759/beam.smp
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4369            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      44386/epmd
```

How can I change the binding address of these ports?